# I left cold homemade butter/sugar cookie dough out of the fridge for 4 hours it was still cold - can i put back in the fridge and use later!

Tags: dough, raw

I left cold homemade butter/sugar cookie dough out of the fridge for 4 hours, but then it was too soft. But still not warm.  Can put back in the refrigerator and use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is probably not going to get the kind of answer you're looking for (and it might be closed).  The reason is this site has specific [rules about food safety questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info), which, I'm guessing, won't fit what you're looking for.  The only kind of answers we can provide are something along the lines of, "food safety organizations such as the FDA and the CDC recommend that you never eat raw cookie dough.  Improper storage could worsen the situation, but it was unsafe to begin with."

Comment: Let me take that dough off your hands and dispose of it properly...